# Firestore security rules: get parameter to use in security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am currently writing some security rules to secure my firestore database, but I am having some issues. I want to be able to get data from my query parameters to put into my rules (I want to be able to use `clientId`):

`db.collection('Users').doc(userId).where('connections', 'array-contains', clientId).get();`

I want to be able to use the `clientId` in my firestore security rules so that I can query another collection using that client id, as I dont think that firestore security rules provides "where" capability in the get queries. Is this at all possible?

Like so:
`request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(clientId)).data.connections`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you found  a solution to this? I am struggling with the same problem.

Comment: @matsmats no, I haven't unfortunatley. I don't think it's possible currently.

Answer (score 0):

I've also been struggling with the same problem for a while and finally managed to solve it:

**Database**

```
/familyMembers/{familyMemberId}
{
    parents 
        userId1
            userId: "userId1"
        userId2
            userId: "userId2"
}
```

**Security rules**

```
match /familyMembers/{familyMemberId}/{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if resource.data.parents[request.auth.uid] != null;
}

match /anotherCollection/{familyMemberId}/{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/familyMembers/$(familyMemberId)).data.parents;
}
```

**Query from Swift code**

```
db.collection("familyMembers").whereField("parents.\(userId).userId", isEqualTo: userId).getDocuments()
```

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/jannica%7Csort:date/firebase-talk/1rTmJmNyJNQ/x2P8vPdqAQAJ

Comment: Your reference URL doesn’t seem to return any appropriate reference for me. Can you verify it?

Comment: @JeremyCaney I'm not sure what you mean by verifying it. It's a very similar question I posted in the Firebase Google Group, and the answer I posted here is a summary of that.

Comment: When I click on the link—at least on a mobile device—I just get redirected to the Google Groups home page. I’m not linked to a page with any relevant information.

Comment: Strange, that happens to me too when I open the link on a mobile device. It should work if you open it on a computer.